# Illustrator shape doesn't fill along path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, fill

[image]When looking very closely at my shapes, the fill is not following the paths I have defined. I have attached a screen shot where you see the blue does not go all the way to the red path. I have never seen this issue before.

Comment: are you sure you don't have 2 paths overlapping? Also is your path closed? Can we see more of the shape?

Comment: To be sure that fill belongs to this path, select path, open Appearance panel and check stroke and fill.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is 4 years old, but I thought I'd share an answer I discovered on the Adobe forum thread here: (https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/fill-doesn-t-match-the-path-created/td-p/10474435)

The solution is:
View > View using CPU

For whatever reason, the GPU view was messing with some of my anchor points, extending the fill color out in an odd, squared-off way beyond the path (image 1 below). I switched it to CPU, and it cleared right up (image 2 below). Hope this helps anyone else coming here for an answer to this question!

[image: Vector fill error with GPU view]

[image: Vector fill issue resolved with CPU view]

Answer (score 0):

If it steers anyone in the right direction, I can replicate it, having experienced it in the past. I can't remember if I managed to fix it.

For me, this only happens when creating a 72ppi RGB document, and then upscaling it (Effect > Document raster effects settings...) to 300ppi. For now, I can only view this at 17,000% zoom: https://postimg.org/image/w797ceuw3/

What % zoom do you have set to get this result, Jessica? If you can, it may be worth pasting everything in to a new, 300ppi document.

Comment: at that zoom level it's most probably just a rendering issue. If it exports fine for your intended purpose, than it's fine.

Comment: Uhn... The  Document Raster Effects item has *zero* effect on vector objects. As the title itself alludes to.. it's for raster elements. While I believe you may be able to recreate this anomaly.. I do not believe the Document Raster Effects setting has *anything* to do with it.